# JS dropdown menu doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some js code, that has to open my menu on hover. But it doesn't react on mouseover/out. Where am i mistaken?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#user-menu').bind('mouseover', openSubMenu);
        jQuery('#user-menu').bind('mouseout', closeSubMenu);

        function openSubMenu() {
            jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'block');    
        };

        function closeSubMenu() {
            jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'none'); 
        };

    });
```

And some html code here

```
<div id="user-menu" class="pull-right btn-group"><a class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">User menu
  <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="user_dropdown_menu"><li class="menu-2 first"><a href="/courses/user">My account</a></li>
<li class="menu-15 last"><a href="/courses/user/logout">Log out</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Looks like it works http://jsfiddle.net/jfHPh/

Comment: wierd, it really works on jsFiddle, but no response on localhost

Comment: did you include jquery.js? What does your local error console say?

Comment: P.S: you don't need `};` at the functions end, just `}`

Comment: You should use hover or mouseenter/mouseleave or hoverintent.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on' /courses/themes/twitter_bootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js?m91x7e:147
(anonymous function) /courses/themes/twitter_bootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js?m91x7e:147
b.extend.ready jquery.js:30
u jquery.js:38

Looks like some issues with protected mode in drupal core

Comment: What version of jquery is that? I think `.on()` was added in 1.4

Comment: updated jQuery, error gone, but still no result on my menu

Comment: Actual issue was caused because of duplicating code in 2 different files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using jQuery's `hover` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#user-menu').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
    });
});
```

Notes:

- passing one function to [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) will fire it for both mouseover and mouseout
- [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) will show or hide depending on the element's current state

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  function openSubMenu() {
         jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'block');
  };
  function closeSubMenu() {
         jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'none');
  };

  jQuery('#user-menu').bind('mouseover', openSubMenu);
  jQuery('#user-menu').bind('mouseout', closeSubMenu);
});
```